# How can I get the maximum value by hour in a list of object using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of custom object that have values and datetimes. If is possible to do How can I filter the object with maximum values by hours.

So grouping the data by date and hours check the objects and get only one by hour witch has the higher value.

For instance I have

```
class CustomObj
{
  public int Id;
  public int Value;
  public DateTime Date;

}

List<CustomObj> listObj = new List<CustomObj>()

listObj.Add(....100 elemets..)

Id     Value    Date
1      4        2014-02-06 11:41:29.507
2      3        2014-02-06 12:11:29.510
3      4        2014-02-06 12:41:29.510
4      0        2014-02-06 13:11:29.510
5      2        2014-02-06 13:41:29.510
6      0        2014-02-06 14:11:29.510
```

So I am trying to get using linq a list that containing the items with Ids (1,3,5,6)

Ids 1,3,5,6 means that I should have a list with the object that from the data of the  table above.
list of custom objects as a result in a table we look like this
   Id     Value    Date
    1      4        2014-02-06 11:41:29.507
    3      4        2014-02-06 12:41:29.510
    5      2        2014-02-06 13:41:29.510
    6      0        2014-02-06 14:11:29.510

Comment: Can you explain why result should be 1,3,5,6?

Comment: Hi Sergey I added details and to what it means basically if I I transform that table in the object that I mentioned I will get only those rows inside the list of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the object with the maximum `Value` for each `Date.Hour` in the dataset, we'll first want to `GroupBy` `Date.Hour`, then for each group select the object whose `Value` is equal to the maximum `Value` in that group, then finally flatten the `Date.Hour` grouping to get a list of objects whose `Value` is the highest among all other objects with the same `Date.Hour`. In code, this looks like:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(element => element.Date.Hour)
                 .SelectMany(group => group.Where(element => element.Value == group.Max(obj => obj.Value)));
```

When run on your data, initialized like:

```
        var list = new List<CustomObj>
                       {
                           new CustomObj {Date = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-06 11:41:29.507"), Id = 1, Value = 4},
                           new CustomObj {Date = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-06 12:11:29.510"), Id = 2, Value = 3},
                           new CustomObj {Date = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-06 12:41:29.510"), Id = 3, Value = 4},
                           new CustomObj {Date = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-06 13:11:29.510"), Id = 4, Value = 0},
                           new CustomObj {Date = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-06 13:41:29.510"), Id = 5, Value = 2},
                           new CustomObj {Date = DateTime.Parse("2014-02-06 14:11:29.510"), Id = 6, Value = 0},
                       };
```

The query returns:

```
Id    Value     Date
1     4         2/6/2014 11:41:29 AM
3     4         2/6/2014 12:41:29 PM
5     2         2/6/2014 1:41:29 PM
6     0         2/6/2014 2:11:29 PM
```

---

By combining [@Sergey Berezovskiy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21614227/1549380)'s and mine, you get a solution much cleaner than my original solution (since mine must iterate over the grouping twice). Simply group the elements by hour like before and `SelectMany` from the groupings after ordering the group members by `Value` and taking one. In code, this is:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(element => element.Date.Hour)
                 .SelectMany(group => group.OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
                                           .Take(1));
```

Which will give the same result while only requiring a single iteration over your collection.

Comment: Hi @Zack I am running into the issue that I want only one maximum values when I have to max number in the same hour range. I tried Take(1) thinking that what that will do is just take only one value but then i realized that that is not working> Could you guide me?

Comment: @Devsined I don't quite understand your question. I think you're asking: given two entries with the same `Date.Hour` and the same `Value`, you want only one of them? In that case, the query above should do exactly that. If instead you want both of them then the query becomes more complex, but can be achieved with a `TakeWhile` (something along the lines of `TakeWhile(e => e.Value == group.Max(g => g.value))`.

Comment: Well have two entry with same Date.Hour and different minutes and with the same values but the query is return both results instead only one.

Comment: This the real query maybe I am missing something  List<CalendarData> listData = filteredlistCalendarData.GroupBy(element =>element.StartTime.Hour).SelectMany(group => group.Where(element => element.EventValue == group.Max(obj => obj.EventValue)).Take(1)).ToList();

Comment: Try using this version:
`var listData = filteredlistCalendarData.GroupBy(element => element.StartTime.Hour).SelectMany(group => group.OrderByDescending(g => g.Value).Take(1));` rather than the `group.Max(...)` version.

Comment: Thanks this have sense I will try it to if this work

Comment: I am trying to filter in a range of day with this query but when I am have in my list different Dates such as 2014/02/20 to 2014/02/10 I am getting only 24 values only with I am assuming that is coz is grouping by hour. I think I will need to add another group before by day. How could I do it? Thank you advance

Answer (score 2):

Getting items with max hour:

```
var objectsWithMaxHour = listObj.GroupBy(o => o.Date.Hour)
                                .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
                                .Take(1)
                                .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Group objects by hour of date. Then sort groups by value of grouping key (i.e. by hour) and take first group. Last step is flattening group items.

NOTE: This query will return single object with id 6 (because it's the only object with hour equal to 14).

Comment: @Habib thanks! At least that is how I understand question. But I still don't understand expected result :)

Comment: I just read docs for `SelectMany` and I still don't get what it does.  Are you flattening the group?  If so, into what?  a single dimension list of objects?  or just one single entry from the found hour?  (What would this return if there were two ID's with same exact datetime?)

Comment: @ebyrob yes, it flattens sequence of object groups into sequence of objects. Thus only one group is taken (group with objects having max hour), it would return objects from that group (i.e. all objects with max hour)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy great explanation!! I finally get it.  Except, you should then only return the first (or a random) from the `.SelectMany()` since the question asked for "only one value".

Comment: @ebyrob actually I edited explanation because I thought it was too complex :)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Hi I edited the question to be more clear I think the Ids caused confusion. What I want to get as a result is the object inside each hour with the higher value. So from 10am to 11am get the object with the higher Value an the same from 11am to 12am ...

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong and you want to:

- group by everything down to an hour (without minutes ans seconds),
- order each group by `Date`
- select `Id` of last element in each group

then this should work

```
var ids = listObj
           .GroupBy(n => new DateTime(n.Date.Year, n.Date.Month, n.Date.Day, n.Date.Hour, 0, 0))
           .Select(g => g.OrderBy(n => n.Date).Last().Id);
```

Answer (score 1):

All of your example data are from one day, so I'm not sure if you want to

1. return a single item for each hour regardless of day
2. return a single item for each combination of hour and day.

Here is code that will meet the second requirement:

```
var lastItemsPerHour = listObj
    .GroupBy(c => new { c.Date.Date, c.Date.Hour },
        (k, ec) => ec.OrderBy(c => c.Date).Last());
```